# Get the value from Second td from each TR

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I had a table that used for user to input their value.

Table Structure:

```
<table id="tblAddProduct">
  <tbody class='A2'>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Code :</td>
      <td> <input/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Description :</td>
      <td> <input/> </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>

   <tbody class='A2'>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Code :</td>
      <td> <input/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Description :</td>
      <td> <input/> </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I had reference other solution and modified to my question. Here is my draft solution:

```
foreach(pq('.A2') as $tag) {
   foreach(pq($tag)->find('tr') as $tr) {
     foreach(pq($tr)->find('td') as $td) {
        echo $td;
     }
   }
}
```

How to get the INPUT from the each second TD from each TR in each TBODY

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique

Comment: @kevinabelita sorry for that. Is my typo. I had modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $html->find('#tblAddProduct tbody.A2 tr') as $tr ) {
    echo $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

I used the plaintext in an example and it worked just fine...

The full working example [`HERE`](http://pastebin.com/2w2g0s4Y) if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `print_r($td);` This will show whats inside. Then you can access it depending on how it is stored.